# Having trouble understanding the purpose of the arguments for Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am having trouble understanding how to use `DropDownListFor`. In the example I have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IterationsDropdown, Model.IterationsDropdown)
```

I have a model where `IterationsDropdown` is a `SelectList`. In both of the arguments I am specifying the same property, which seems like a duplication to me.

What is the meaning of the two arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument is a property on your model that will hold the selected value from the `DropDownList` and the second contains the actual select list that generates the options within the HTML select. In your example, assuming that the `IterationsDropDownList` has an integer Id property, you would need to create a property for the selected id:

```
public int SelectedId { get; set; }
```

and your extension method call then becomes this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedId, Model.IterationsDropdown)
```

Then, in your Controller Action method, you can pass in any type with an integer property called `SelectedId` (it could be your `ViewModel` but it doesn't have to be - it could also be a `Command` if you're following the command query pattern, for example) and it will contain the id of the selected option from the `DropDownList` when the form is posted back to the server.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionMethod(YourViewModel viewModel)
{
    // do something with viewModel.SelectedId
}
```

Comment: Any idea what I would do if I did not want a selected value? Is it possible to use DropDownListFor in that case?

Comment: In that case, just use `@Html.DropDownList` instead